# C# Regular expressions. OR condition in lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex

I have text with some urls inside. There can be 3 types of urls

1. *without protocol   Ex: www.website-link.ch*
2. *with http.         Ex: http:// www.website-link.ch*
3. *with https         Ex: https:// www.website-link.ch*

I need to get address part from all url (ex: website-link.ch). For it I need a regular expression that will have a positive lookbehind if something starts with 'www.' **OR**  with 'http:// www.' **OR**  with 'https:// www.'

It it possible to put OR condition inside positive lookbehind? For me it did not work and I created only this monster.

```
string pattern = @"((?<=http://www\.).*\b)|((?<=https://www\.).*\b)|((?<=www\.).*\b)";
```

Is it possible to make a pattern smarter?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding this correctly. What do you want to capture exactly? the url `website-link.ch` regardless whether it has `www.`,  `http:// www` or  `https:// www.` ?

Comment: I recently had to do the same thing. I did it using  2 different regex. Used this for the http/https.  `@"(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)"`

Comment: Can't you simply use [`www.(.*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rY0hR3/1)

Comment: My two regex method gives results like if you gave 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions.....' you would get 'stackoverflow.com' if you gave 'https://www.google.com/search?....' you would get 'google.com'. If that sounds like what you want i can post the code as an answer. But it doesnt exactly answer the question of a smarter pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using lookbehind in this case by simply having the protocol and "www." parts be in non-captured groups.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:https?://)?www\.)(.*\b)");
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EkSrOsQ07w1uMwoY)

Only the text matched by `(.*\b)` will be captured since all the other groups use the non-capturing `(?:)` syntax.

The hostname of the website address (without "www.") can then be accessed by checking out the captured groups of the match:

```
var hostnameMatch = regex.Match("http://www.website-link.ch").Groups[1];
if (hostnameMatch.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Matched: {0}", hostnameMatch.Value); // Outputs "Matched: website-link.ch"
```

MSDN has some [more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the properties available for each matched group.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `System.UriBuilder` class which has built-in functionality to parse a string and separate the parts.

For example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "www.website-link.ch";
        var builder = new UriBuilder(s);
        if (builder.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String starts with `https`");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("String does not start with `https`");
    }
}
```